# Perl regex substitution: Substitute particular string, if another particular string is not on the same line

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation, substitution

I have text like this:

```
Hi
... OK ... Replace ...
... BAD ... Replace ...
Hi
```

I want to replace all "Replace" strings with "Done" if and only if "BAD" is not anywhere on the same line. So the only line that should be modified is the second line in the example I've given. I'm struggling to do this, I've tried the following which does not work:

`perl -i'' -pe 's/^(?!BAD)Replace/$1Done/g' TEST`

Can this be done in a single expression like what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Does the `BAD` have to be before the `Replace` string or can be anywhere on the line?

Comment: It can be either, as there should never be the case where BAD comes after Replace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to do too much in a single regex. This is much more straightforward and easier to get right

```
perl -pe "s/Replace/Done/ unless /BAD/" mydata
```

**output**

```
Hi
... OK ... Done ...
... BAD ... Replace ...
Hi
```

Comment: Great, thank you. This seems to work perfectly. Does this mean Perl looks at each line separately?

Comment: All I needed to add was the g modifier to replace more than one occurrence.

Comment: The Perl's command line option `-p` puts a `while (<>) { ...; print }` loop around your code, so yes in this case it's applying the code to each line separately

Comment: Ah okay. I didn't understand that there could be several `Replace` strings in one line of your data. It always helps yo post your *real* data if at all possible

Comment: Huh? Surely, this only checks if the word BAD is not on the same line before making the substitution - but the OP specifically said BAD may not occur BEFORE...

Comment: Oh, I see the comment now.. `preceded` in the title and the question both mean BEFORE or AFTER !!!

Comment: I changed the question. The data should never have the "BAD" afterwards, but it doesn't matter if the solution doesn't match in this case (a case which never occurs).

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one `Replace` on the line you can use something like

```
s/^(?!.*BAD.*Replace)(.*)Replace/$1Done/
```

The negative look ahead will check there isn't any `BAD` before the `Replace` on this line. If so, you replace the `Replace` with `Done`.

Comment: Neither the `/g` nor the `/m` modifiers are of any use here

Comment: Ah, apparently from what the OP is saying there can be multiple `Replace` strings in a line, so I was wrong about the `/g`. My apologies

Comment: @Borodin: This regex only catches the first occurrence of `Replace`, so your comment is still actually relevant

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `sed` if that is what you mean:

```
sed -i -e '/BAD/!s/Replace/Done/' TEST
```

Comment: The `sed` solution is even easier if you are allowing BAD to be before or after the replacement.